# Html Radio Button checked function don't when i use media query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

basically i had 2  having same radio buttons. first is for desktop view and second is for mobile view i have hide then according to media size using media query.

problem my 1st div checked function is working on desktop view but when it changes to mobile view it don't works?

```
            <div class="gen-div">
                <div class="form-group gen-label">
                    <label class="col-sm-12 lab" for="id_gender">Gender *</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group gen-div-margin">
                    <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding:12px;"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked/> <label>Male</label></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding:12px;"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/> <label>Female</label></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding:12px;"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"/> <label>Other</label></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group gen-div1">
                <label class="col-sm-2 lab" for='id_gender'>Gender *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding:12px;">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked/> <label>Male</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 " style="padding:12px;">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/> <label>Female</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding:12px;">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"/> <label>Other</label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**gen-div** is for desktop view and
**gen-div1** is for mobile view

i know this is basic question but i need help !!!

this my css
    .

```
.gen-div{display:none;}
 .gen-div1{display:block;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px)
 {
.gen-div{display:block;} .gen-div1{display:none;}}
```

Comment: Could you also include the CSS you have used?

Comment: .gen-div{display:block;} .gen-div1{display:none;}   @media only screen and (max-width: 500px)
{  .gen-div{display:none;} .gen-div1{display:block;}

Comment: And what media queries did you use?

Comment: where is your media query closing bracket?? @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) { .gen-div{display:none;} .gen-div1{display:block;}

Comment: check in the question

Comment: sorry i have closed the bracket of media query. but still not working

Comment: Creating a jsfiddle with your code I cannot replicate the problem you have https://jsfiddle.net/4uu2tg15/ . Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @lonut problem is simple but complicated

Comment: @lonut have to see it on mobile view problem is at when  you resize the screen to mobile view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.gen-div {display:block;} // used for desktop shown by default
.gen-div1 {display:none;} // used for mobile hidden by default

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) { // mobile media query
.gen-div {display:none;} // used for desktop hidden when on mobile
.gen-div1 {display:block;} // used for mobile shown when on mobile   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **gen-div** is for desktop view and **gen-div1** is for mobile view

You have **.gen-div1** for mobile view and **.gen-div** for desktop view, but your CSS implies you mixed them. Either change the CSS or change the classes in the HTML:

```
.gen-div {display:none;} // used for desktop but hidden by default
.gen-div1 {display:block;} // used for mobile but shown by default

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) { // mobile media query
    .gen-div {display:block;} // used for desktop shown when on mobile
    .gen-div1 {display:none;} // used for mobile hidden when on mobile
}
```

should be:

```
.gen-div {display:block;} // used for desktop shown by default
.gen-div1 {display:none;} // used for mobile hidden by default

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) { // mobile media query
    .gen-div {display:none;} // used for desktop hidden when on mobile
    .gen-div1 {display:block;} // used for mobile shown when on mobile
}
```

Comment: i have try the above code. but now problem is in desktop view radio button checked function run but no it mobile view

Comment: What javascript code do you use? Can you add the code to your question.

Comment: i have not use any java-script only css and html